# Convex cone of functions of the form $a\log(1+bx + ?)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the set of all functions
\begin{align}
f_{a,b}(x): [0, \infty) &\to [0, \infty) \\
x &\mapsto a\log(1+bx)
\end{align}

Is there a way of making the set of these functions $S =\{f_{a,b}: a,b \ge 0\}$ have the property that $\left[f_{a,b} + f_{a',b'}\right] \in S$?  Can this be done by adding a fixed number of extra parameters to the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: the functions $\log(1+bx)$ for different $b > 0$ are linearly independent, so you would need infinitely many parameters.  A way to see that they are linearly independent is to look at their derivatives, $\dfrac{b}{1+bx}$, which have poles at different points $x=-1/b$.

Comment: Is it true that if the derivatives are linearly independent the functions are also linearly  independet ?

Comment: Yes, because differentiation is linear: if a linear combination of the functions is $0$, the corresponding linear combination of the derivatives is also $0$.